# Merging time and date data with associated values

Tags: r, merge

I hope somebody can help me with this. Below's a sample of the data I'm working on:

```
> print(sampleinput)
                Time ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z
 1: 6/19/18 10:40:00         60         74         95
 2: 6/19/18 10:41:20         62         63         88
 3: 6/19/18 10:42:40         60         56         82
 4: 6/19/18 10:44:00         66         61         90
 5: 6/19/18 10:45:20         60         53         80
 6: 6/19/18 10:46:40         57         40         70
 7: 6/19/18 10:48:00         54         41         68
 8: 6/19/18 10:49:20         52         49         71
 9: 6/19/18 10:50:40         61         49         78
10: 6/19/18 10:52:00         93         32         98
11: 6/19/18 10:53:20         80         54         97
12: 6/19/18 10:54:40         73         39         83
13: 6/19/18 10:56:00         47         37         60
14: 6/19/18 10:57:20         51         55         75
15: 6/19/18 10:58:40         51         60         79
16: 6/19/18 11:00:00         14         13         19
17: 6/19/18 11:01:20          0          0          0
18: 6/19/18 11:02:40         13          3         13
19: 6/19/18 11:04:00         20         10         22
20: 6/19/18 11:05:20         13          6         14
```

Below's a sample of how I would like my data to be transformed:

```
> print(sampleoutput)
               Time ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z
1: 6/19/18 10:40:00          0          0          0
2: 6/19/18 10:44:00        188        180        260
3: 6/19/18 10:48:00        171        134        218
4: 6/19/18 10:52:00        206        130        247
5: 6/19/18 10:56:00        200        130        240
6: 6/19/18 11:00:00        116        128        173
7: 6/19/18 11:04:00         33         13         35
```

As you can see on column `Time`, date and time measures have been taken every 80 seconds with associated values for columns `ACTIVITY_X`, `ACTIITY_Y` and `ACTIVITY_Z`.

I would like to transform my dataset in a way so that instead of having date and time measures every 80 seconds, I will have them every 240 seconds (4 minutes).

As for the values in columns `ACTIVITY_X`, `ACTIITY_Y` and `ACTIVITY_Z`, that would imply summing them every three rows to a single row. Note that, for each time, its associated `ACTIVITY_X`, `ACTIITY_Y` and `ACTIVITY_Z` measures are calculated from an interval corresponding to: [previous time + 1 seconds to actual time].

Example: For the second line with time `6/19/18 10:41:20` values for `ACTIVITY_X`, `ACTIITY_Y` and `ACTIVITY_Z` correspond to a sampling interval of  [6/19/18 10:40:01 to 6/19/18 10:41:20].

The first row of the output table will have 0 for `ACTIVITY_X`, `ACTIITY_Y` and `ACTIVITY_Z` values since I'm missing the values from the two previous time intervals, but that's no problem.

I'm quite new to R and although I've been able to transform my data with Excel I would like to automat this process which seems quite complex.

Hope this is an interesting question and any input is appreciated!

PS: I can't use dput since too big dataset, but I've uploaded it [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Gt5Ju1ouNQ2MV61T7ov3pg410f-BgDOe)

Answer (score 2):

`lubridate` should have the functionality you need.

Looks like you are using `data.table` already, so using that here...

```
    X <- data.table(sampleinput)

    X$Time <- as.POSIXct(X$Time, format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S')

    X$tgroup <- lubridate::ceiling_date(X$Time, '4 mins')

    X[, list( x = sum(ACTIVITY_X), 
              y = sum(ACTIVITY_Y), 
              z =sum(ACTIVITY_Z) ), by = list (tgroup)]
```

Returns

```
                tgroup   x   y   z
1: 2018-06-19 10:40:00  60  74  95
2: 2018-06-19 10:44:00 188 180 260
3: 2018-06-19 10:48:00 171 134 218
4: 2018-06-19 10:52:00 206 130 247
5: 2018-06-19 10:56:00 200 130 240
6: 2018-06-19 11:00:00 116 128 173
7: 2018-06-19 11:04:00  33  13  35
8: 2018-06-19 11:08:00  13   6  14
```

You could change the boundary case (first line) manually if necessary

Comment: I followed your code but I'm getting the following errors: ```> X <- data.table(sampleinput)
> X$tgroup <- lubridate::ceiling_date(X$Time, '4 mins')
Error in UseMethod("reclass_date", orig) : 
  no applicable method for 'reclass_date' applied to an object of class "character"
In addition: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 
> X[, list( x = sum(ACTIVITY_X), 
+           y = sum(ACTIVITY_Y), 
+           z =sum(ACTIVITY_Z) ), by = list (tgroup)]
Error in eval(bysub, x, parent.frame()) : object 'tgroup' not found``` Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: This was using the whole dataset. I've uploaded it in my original post if that helps!

Comment: Looks like you need to convert the column X$Time to a relevant date-time class (e.g. POSIXct ). I edited the answer above